# How can I get my Python Code to restart when the network disconnects

Tags: python, json, logging, restart, disconnect

I have a piece of Python Code running as a service that pulls weather data via API.

The code itself runs perfectly fine when everything is hunky dory, ie the network, but I have noticed that sometimes the WiFi on the Pi that is pulling the API data will drop and then the python codes seems to stop.

I have a small line of code providing the most basic of logs, but I would like to improve upon it greatly. The log code just provides me with the datetime.now so I can see when the last time the code ran was.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#import modules
import cymysql
from time import sleep
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import datetime

#set MySQl Variables
host = "localhost"
user = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
schema = "xxx"

#connect to MySQL DB
db = cymysql.connect(host, user, password, schema)
curs = db.cursor()

#set api key for DarkSky API
apikey="xxx"
# Latitude & longitude
lati="-26.20227"
longi="28.04363"

# Add units=si to get it in sensible ISO units.
url="https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"+apikey+"/"+lati+","+longi+"?units=si"

#begin infinite loop
while True:

        #convert API reading to json and readable array 'weather'
        meteo=urlopen(url).read()
        meteo = meteo.decode('utf-8')
        weather = json.loads(meteo)

        #set variables for current weather
        cTemp = (weather['currently']['temperature'])
        cCond = (weather['currently']['summary'])
        cRain1 =  (weather['currently']['precipProbability'])
        cRain2 = cRain1*100
        cIcon = (weather['currently']['icon'])
        oaSum = (weather['daily']['summary'])

        #print variables - for testing purposes
        #print (cTemp)
        #print (cCond)
        #print (cRain2)
        #print (cIcon)
        #print (oaSum)

        #extract daily data from 'weather' array
        daily = (weather['daily']['data'])

        #create new arrays for daily variables
        listHigh = []
        listLow = []
        listCond = []
        listRain = []
        listIcon = []

        #set daily variables
        for i in daily:
                listHigh.append(i['temperatureHigh'])

        for i in range(0,len(listHigh)):
                high1 = listHigh[0]
                high2 = listHigh[1]
                high3 = listHigh[2]
                high4 = listHigh[3]
                high5 = listHigh[4]
                high6 = listHigh[5]
                high7 = listHigh[6]
                high8 = listHigh[7]

        for o in daily:
                listLow.append(o['temperatureLow'])

        for o in range(0,len(listLow)):
                low1 = listLow[0]
                low2 = listLow[1]
                low3 = listLow[2]
                low4 = listLow[3]
                low5 = listLow[4]
                low6 = listLow[5]
                low7 = listLow[6]
                low8 = listLow[7]

        for p in daily:
                listCond.append(p['summary'])

        for p in range(0,len(listCond)):
                cond1 = listCond[0]
                cond2 = listCond[1]
                cond3 = listCond[2]
                cond4 = listCond[3]
                cond5 = listCond[4]
                cond6 = listCond[5]
                cond7 = listCond[6]
                cond8 = listCond[7]

        for m in daily:
                listRain.append(m['precipProbability'])

        for m in range(0,len(listRain)):
                rain1 = listRain[0]
                rain2 = listRain[1]
                rain3 = listRain[2]
                rain4 = listRain[3]
                rain5 = listRain[4]
                rain6 = listRain[5]
                rain7 = listRain[6]
                rain8 = listRain[7]

        #convert rain chance to readable percentage
        prain1 = rain1*100
        prain2 = rain2*100
        prain3 = rain3*100
        prain4 = rain4*100
        prain5 = rain5*100
        prain6 = rain6*100
        prain7 = rain7*100
        prain8 = rain8*100

        for l in daily:
                listIcon.append(l['icon'])

        for l in range (0,len(listIcon)):
                icon1 = listIcon[0]
                icon2 = listIcon[1]
                icon3 = listIcon[2]
                icon4 = listIcon[3]
                icon5 = listIcon[4]
                icon6 = listIcon[5]
                icon7 = listIcon[6]
                icon8 = listIcon[7]

        #print daily variables - for testing purposes
        #print (high1)
        #print (low1)
        #print (cond1)
        #print (prain1)
        #print (icon1)
        #print (high2)
        #print (low2)
        #print (cond2)
        #print (prain2)
        #print (icon2)

        #update data in DataBase
        try:
                sql_update_query = """UPDATE weather SET current_temp = %s, cur$
                varis = (cTemp, cCond, cRain2, cIcon, high1, low1, cond1, prain$
                curs.execute(sql_update_query, varis)
                db.commit()
        except db.Error as error:
                print("Error: {}".format(error))
                db.rollback()

        #write date to log file
        with open ("/home/pi/CoRo/Projects/WeatherMan/weatherlog.txt", mode="w") as file:
                file.write('Last Data was pulled at: %s' %(datetime.datetime.now()))
        #set loop to sleep for 10 minutes and go again
        sleep(600)
```

I understand that the Database Code is snipped, but it is just the variables being put in to the database, which I can see works.

However if the network disconnects, the code stops and the database is left with the last polled API data.

How would I restart the python code if the API get fails?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think the best solution is to you create a service that check for the network and if the network is down restart your API but in this case if there were variable in memory that need be save you lose them....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite the portion of your code that pulls the weather data as a function or separate module. This would allow you to call it only when the network connection is working. Some pseudo code below:

```py
if network_connection:
    pull_weather_data()
else:
    do_something()
```

`do_something()` could be an effort to reconnect to the network, such as resetting your network adapter.

You could determine the state of the network connection by trying to ping your router or an external IP like one of Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4).

To avoid nested loops you could use the `continue` clause. For example:

```py
while True:
    if network_connection:
        pull_weather_data()
    else:
        reset_network_connection()
        time.sleep(180) # Sleep for 3 minutes.
        continue
```

The `continue` will send the interpreter back to the start of the `while` loop. From there it will check the network connection and either pull data or reset the network connection and sleep for another 3 minutes.

Comment: since `network_connection` is `boolean`, your `elif` makes no much sense. Ordinary `else` suffices.

Comment: Good point. This was just meant as example code but I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: So, as an example; Start the While True Loop -> Check if can ping 8.8.8.8 -> if True, run code as normal? The If False part though, is where I am getting a little confused, as I see it, it would go: if False, reset network adaptors, wait 1/2/3 minutes, then check the 8.8.8.8 ping again, if true run code as normal but then I would need to keep nesting if statements for every time the 8.8.8.8 ping fails

Comment: I don't think you'd need to nest the loops how you've suggested. I've updated my answer to hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey Quernon, for ease of visibility I have re-posted the code as an answer below, pretty much using the network check you suggested, does it look correct?

Comment: Do I need to add `continue` to the end of the true half of the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Using Quernons answer above the code has been edited as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#import modules
import os
import cymysql
from time import sleep
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import datetime

#set MySQl Variables
host = "localhost"
user = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
schema = "xxx"

#connect to MySQL DB
db = cymysql.connect(host, user, password, schema)
curs = db.cursor()

#set api key for DarkSky API
apikey="xxx"
# Latitude & longitude
lati="-26.20227"
longi="28.04363"

# Add units=si to get it in sensible ISO units not stupid Fahreneheit.
url="https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"+apikey+"/"+lati+","+longi+"?units=si"

#begin infinite loop
while True:

        #function to check if there is an internet connection
        def check_ping():
                hostname = "8.8.8.8"
                response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
                #and then check the response...
                if response == 0:
                        pingstatus = 0
                else:
                        pingstatus = 1

                return pingstatus

        networkstatus = check_ping()

        #print check_ping() - for testing purposes
        #print (networkstatus)

        #function to pull weather data from API
        def get_weather():
          #insert weather data here with no changes

        if networkstatus == 0:
                get_weather()
        else:
                print ("Resetting Network Adapters")
                dwnnw = 'ifconfig wlan0 down'
                upnw = 'ifconfig wlan0 up'
                os.system(dwnnw)
                os.system(upnw)
                sleep(180)
                continue
```